# Making section Responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make my section responsive by making the (trending item) appear 2 instead of 1 in the mobile width. I am planning to have like 20 items making it long and the website not that attractive. I would love help in making them 2. Thanks.

```css
.trending
{
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 105px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.trending_container
{
    margin-top: 90px;
}
.trending_item
{
    margin-bottom: 55px;
}
.trending_image
{
    width: 82px;
    height: 76px;
    float: left;
}
.trending_image img
{
    width: 100%;
}
.trending_content
{
    padding-left: 94px;
}
.trending_title
{
    margin-top: -5px;
}
.trending_title a
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #2d2c2c;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 200ms ease;
    transition: all 200ms ease;
}
.trending_title a:hover
{
    color: #fa9e1b;
}
.trending_price
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fa9e1b;
}
.trending_location
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #929191;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.clearfix::before, .clearfix::after
{
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix::after
{
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix
{
    zoom: 1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 575px)
{
  .trending_title a
{
  font-size: 14px;
}
.trending_price
{
  font-size: 12px;
}
.trending_location
{
  font-size: 12px;
}
.offers_image_container
{
  height: calc((100vw - 30px) / 0.974);
}
.trending_item
{
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.trending {
position: static;}

}
```

```html
  <div class="trending">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
          <p class="title-bg-small wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="300ms">Activities</p>
          <h3 class="section-title wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="400ms">What to do in
            <span>Nairobi</span></h3>

            <p style="color: #414240;"> Enquire for any of the activities and a tour guide will be designated to ensure smooth travelling and execution
              of all activities done to perfection. 
            </p>
        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row trending_container">


                <!-- Trending Item -->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="trending_item clearfix">
                        <div class="trending_image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311354905-789ff5f7a457?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" alt="https://unsplash.com/@fransaraco"></div>
                        <div class="trending_content">
                            <div class="trending_title"><a href="#">Shopping at Maasai Market</a></div>
                            <div class="trending_price">From $182</div>
                            <div class="trending_location">madrid, spain</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Trending Item -->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="trending_item clearfix">
                        <div class="trending_image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311354905-789ff5f7a457?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" alt="https://unsplash.com/@grovemade"></div>
                        <div class="trending_content">
                            <div class="trending_title"><a href="#">Nairobi National Park Game Drive</a></div>
                            <div class="trending_price">From $182</div>
                            <div class="trending_location">madrid, spain</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Trending Item -->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="trending_item clearfix">
                        <div class="trending_image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311354905-789ff5f7a457?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" alt="https://unsplash.com/@jbriscoe"></div>
                        <div class="trending_content">
                            <div class="trending_title"><a href="#">queen hotel</a></div>
                            <div class="trending_price">From $182</div>
                            <div class="trending_location">madrid, spain</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Trending Item -->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="trending_item clearfix">
                        <div class="trending_image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311354905-789ff5f7a457?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" alt="https://unsplash.com/@oowgnuj"></div>
                        <div class="trending_content">
                            <div class="trending_title"><a href="#">mars hotel</a></div>
                            <div class="trending_price">From $182</div>
                            <div class="trending_location">madrid, spain</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Trending Item -->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="trending_item clearfix">
                        <div class="trending_image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311354905-789ff5f7a457?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" alt="https://unsplash.com/@mindaugas"></div>
                        <div class="trending_content">
                            <div class="trending_title"><a href="#">grand hotel</a></div>
                            <div class="trending_price">From $182</div>
                            <div class="trending_location">madrid, spain</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Trending Item -->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="trending_item clearfix">
                        <div class="trending_image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311354905-789ff5f7a457?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" alt="https://unsplash.com/@itsnwa"></div>
                        <div class="trending_content">
                            <div class="trending_title"><a href="#">mars hotel</a></div>
                            <div class="trending_price">From $182</div>
                            <div class="trending_location">madrid, spain</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Trending Item -->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="trending_item clearfix">
                        <div class="trending_image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311354905-789ff5f7a457?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" alt="https://unsplash.com/@rktkn"></div>
                        <div class="trending_content">
                            <div class="trending_title"><a href="#">queen hotel</a></div>
                            <div class="trending_price">From $182</div>
                            <div class="trending_location">madrid, spain</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Trending Item -->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="trending_item clearfix">
                        <div class="trending_image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311354905-789ff5f7a457?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80"></div>
                        <div class="trending_content">
                            <div class="trending_title"><a href="#">mars hotel</a></div>
                            <div class="trending_price">From $182</div>
                            <div class="trending_location">madrid, spain</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: which version of bootstrap you are using?

Comment: its hard to understand what you really mean. Can you make a drawing of the prefered layout?

Comment: @j08691 I'm using Bootsatrap version 4.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your items to be on 2 columns instead of 1 for mobile, you must add:

- `col-xs-6` for Bootstrap 3 (minimum col will be always `col-xs-x`)
- `col-6` for Bootstrap 4 (minimum col will be always `col-x`)

Bootstrap 3:

```css
.trending
{
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 105px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.trending_container
{
    margin-top: 90px;
}
.trending_item
{
    margin-bottom: 55px;
}
.trending_image
{
    width: 82px;
    height: 76px;
    float: left;
}
.trending_image img
{
    width: 100%;
}
.trending_content
{
    padding-left: 94px;
}
.trending_title
{
    margin-top: -5px;
}
.trending_title a
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #2d2c2c;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 200ms ease;
    transition: all 200ms ease;
}
.trending_title a:hover
{
    color: #fa9e1b;
}
.trending_price
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fa9e1b;
}
.trending_location
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #929191;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.clearfix::before, .clearfix::after
{
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix::after
{
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix
{
    zoom: 1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 575px)
{
  .trending_title a
{
  font-size: 14px;
}
.trending_price
{
  font-size: 12px;
}
.trending_location
{
  font-size: 12px;
}
.offers_image_container
{
  height: calc((100vw - 30px) / 0.974);
}
.trending_item
{
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.trending {
position: static;}

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.css" integrity="sha512-qwBwa3tCXzwsUi4qaXeRMWS/CEeG5iNVpZz98o83NwoDdpbm1ss00GaALwCmXEnr6pQoVm49JaNMKuWvuoHKJA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="trending">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
          <p class="title-bg-small wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="300ms">Activities</p>
          <h3 class="section-title wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="400ms">What to do in
            <span>Nairobi</span></h3>

            <p style="color: #414240;"> Enquire for any of the activities and a tour guide will be designated to ensure smooth travelling and execution
              of all activities done to perfection. 
            </p>
        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row trending_container">


                <!-- Trending Item -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="trending_item clearfix">
                        <div class="trending_image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311354905-789ff5f7a457?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" alt="https://unsplash.com/@fransaraco"></div>
                        <div class="trending_content">
                            <div class="trending_title"><a href="#">Shopping at Maasai Market</a></div>
                            <div class="trending_price">From $182</div>
                            <div class="trending_location">madrid, spain</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Trending Item -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="trending_item clearfix">
                        <div class="trending_image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311354905-789ff5f7a457?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" alt="https://unsplash.com/@grovemade"></div>
                        <div class="trending_content">
                            <div class="trending_title"><a href="#">Nairobi National Park Game Drive</a></div>
                            <div class="trending_price">From $182</div>
                            <div class="trending_location">madrid, spain</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Trending Item -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="trending_item clearfix">
                        <div class="trending_image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311354905-789ff5f7a457?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" alt="https://unsplash.com/@jbriscoe"></div>
                        <div class="trending_content">
                            <div class="trending_title"><a href="#">queen hotel</a></div>
                            <div class="trending_price">From $182</div>
                            <div class="trending_location">madrid, spain</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Trending Item -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="trending_item clearfix">
                        <div class="trending_image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311354905-789ff5f7a457?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" alt="https://unsplash.com/@oowgnuj"></div>
                        <div class="trending_content">
                            <div class="trending_title"><a href="#">mars hotel</a></div>
                            <div class="trending_price">From $182</div>
                            <div class="trending_location">madrid, spain</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Trending Item -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="trending_item clearfix">
                        <div class="trending_image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311354905-789ff5f7a457?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" alt="https://unsplash.com/@mindaugas"></div>
                        <div class="trending_content">
                            <div class="trending_title"><a href="#">grand hotel</a></div>
                            <div class="trending_price">From $182</div>
                            <div class="trending_location">madrid, spain</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Trending Item -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="trending_item clearfix">
                        <div class="trending_image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311354905-789ff5f7a457?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" alt="https://unsplash.com/@itsnwa"></div>
                        <div class="trending_content">
                            <div class="trending_title"><a href="#">mars hotel</a></div>
                            <div class="trending_price">From $182</div>
                            <div class="trending_location">madrid, spain</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Trending Item -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="trending_item clearfix">
                        <div class="trending_image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311354905-789ff5f7a457?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" alt="https://unsplash.com/@rktkn"></div>
                        <div class="trending_content">
                            <div class="trending_title"><a href="#">queen hotel</a></div>
                            <div class="trending_price">From $182</div>
                            <div class="trending_location">madrid, spain</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Trending Item -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="trending_item clearfix">
                        <div class="trending_image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311354905-789ff5f7a457?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80"></div>
                        <div class="trending_content">
                            <div class="trending_title"><a href="#">mars hotel</a></div>
                            <div class="trending_price">From $182</div>
                            <div class="trending_location">madrid, spain</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Bootsrap 4:

```css
.trending
{
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 105px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.trending_container
{
    margin-top: 90px;
}
.trending_item
{
    margin-bottom: 55px;
}
.trending_image
{
    width: 82px;
    height: 76px;
    float: left;
}
.trending_image img
{
    width: 100%;
}
.trending_content
{
    padding-left: 94px;
}
.trending_title
{
    margin-top: -5px;
}
.trending_title a
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #2d2c2c;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 200ms ease;
    transition: all 200ms ease;
}
.trending_title a:hover
{
    color: #fa9e1b;
}
.trending_price
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fa9e1b;
}
.trending_location
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #929191;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.clearfix::before, .clearfix::after
{
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix::after
{
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix
{
    zoom: 1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 575px)
{
  .trending_title a
{
  font-size: 14px;
}
.trending_price
{
  font-size: 12px;
}
.trending_location
{
  font-size: 12px;
}
.offers_image_container
{
  height: calc((100vw - 30px) / 0.974);
}
.trending_item
{
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.trending {
position: static;}

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="trending">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
          <p class="title-bg-small wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="300ms">Activities</p>
          <h3 class="section-title wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="400ms">What to do in
            <span>Nairobi</span></h3>

            <p style="color: #414240;"> Enquire for any of the activities and a tour guide will be designated to ensure smooth travelling and execution
              of all activities done to perfection. 
            </p>
        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row trending_container">


                <!-- Trending Item -->
                <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="trending_item clearfix">
                        <div class="trending_image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311354905-789ff5f7a457?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" alt="https://unsplash.com/@fransaraco"></div>
                        <div class="trending_content">
                            <div class="trending_title"><a href="#">Shopping at Maasai Market</a></div>
                            <div class="trending_price">From $182</div>
                            <div class="trending_location">madrid, spain</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Trending Item -->
                <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="trending_item clearfix">
                        <div class="trending_image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311354905-789ff5f7a457?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" alt="https://unsplash.com/@grovemade"></div>
                        <div class="trending_content">
                            <div class="trending_title"><a href="#">Nairobi National Park Game Drive</a></div>
                            <div class="trending_price">From $182</div>
                            <div class="trending_location">madrid, spain</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Trending Item -->
                <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="trending_item clearfix">
                        <div class="trending_image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311354905-789ff5f7a457?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" alt="https://unsplash.com/@jbriscoe"></div>
                        <div class="trending_content">
                            <div class="trending_title"><a href="#">queen hotel</a></div>
                            <div class="trending_price">From $182</div>
                            <div class="trending_location">madrid, spain</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Trending Item -->
                <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="trending_item clearfix">
                        <div class="trending_image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311354905-789ff5f7a457?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" alt="https://unsplash.com/@oowgnuj"></div>
                        <div class="trending_content">
                            <div class="trending_title"><a href="#">mars hotel</a></div>
                            <div class="trending_price">From $182</div>
                            <div class="trending_location">madrid, spain</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Trending Item -->
                <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="trending_item clearfix">
                        <div class="trending_image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311354905-789ff5f7a457?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" alt="https://unsplash.com/@mindaugas"></div>
                        <div class="trending_content">
                            <div class="trending_title"><a href="#">grand hotel</a></div>
                            <div class="trending_price">From $182</div>
                            <div class="trending_location">madrid, spain</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Trending Item -->
                <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="trending_item clearfix">
                        <div class="trending_image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311354905-789ff5f7a457?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" alt="https://unsplash.com/@itsnwa"></div>
                        <div class="trending_content">
                            <div class="trending_title"><a href="#">mars hotel</a></div>
                            <div class="trending_price">From $182</div>
                            <div class="trending_location">madrid, spain</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Trending Item -->
                <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="trending_item clearfix">
                        <div class="trending_image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311354905-789ff5f7a457?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" alt="https://unsplash.com/@rktkn"></div>
                        <div class="trending_content">
                            <div class="trending_title"><a href="#">queen hotel</a></div>
                            <div class="trending_price">From $182</div>
                            <div class="trending_location">madrid, spain</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Trending Item -->
                <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="trending_item clearfix">
                        <div class="trending_image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311354905-789ff5f7a457?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80"></div>
                        <div class="trending_content">
                            <div class="trending_title"><a href="#">mars hotel</a></div>
                            <div class="trending_price">From $182</div>
                            <div class="trending_location">madrid, spain</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```